# Prove by induction that $7^n < n!$ for all integer $n \ge 21$

Tags: induction

Prove by induction that $7^n < n!\,$ for all integers $n\ge 21$

Comment: Please check whether it is $7n$ or $7^n$. Your question and heading didn't match

Comment: Actually It is 7^n

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: yes but i dont understand, base case is when n=21, is it true for base case?

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi Do you know if we can verify the base case easily (w/o calculator)?

Comment: @columbus8myhw: I modified my answer. Please take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1:** Is $7^{21}<21!$  ?
If yes, move to step 2.

**Step 2:** Suppose this holds for some $k(\ge 21)\in \mathbb{N}$

Now you need to show that if the condition holds for $k$, it also holds for $k+1$

**Step 3:** *Easy-peasy*. $7^{k}<k!$ holds and you need to show $7^{k+1}<(k+1)!$. What should you do?

**Edit** For **Step 1**

$\prod_{n=14}^{21}n>(14)^7\cdot21=2^7\cdot 3\cdot 7^8$

Also, $\prod_{n=7}^{13}n>7^6\cdot 13$

Combining both equations

$\prod_{n=7}^{21}n>2^7\cdot 3\cdot 7^{14}\cdot 13$

or

$21!=\prod_{n=1}^{21}n>1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6\cdot 2^7\cdot 3\cdot 7^{14}\cdot 13$

Rearranging the terms

$21!=\prod_{n=1}^{21}n>(1\cdot2^3)\cdot (2\cdot 2^2) \cdot (3\cdot 3)\cdot (4\cdot 2)\cdot (5\cdot 2)\cdot 6\cdot 7^{14}\cdot 13$

$21!>6\cdot 7^{19}\cdot 13$

$21!>7^{21}$

Comment: I can rewrite 7^k+1  as 7^k * 7

Comment: Yes. And $7^k\cdot 7<k!\cdot 7<k!\cdot(k+1)$. That is because $k\ge 21>7$ and so is $k+1$. Were you able to show this for the base case or do you need help?

Comment: thank you very much for your kind help)))

Comment: You're welcome. I got stuck somewhere while proving and it took me a while to know where I was going wrong