# Which is the first $n$ such that $100^n < n!$?

Tags: limits, number-theory

I know that $\lim \sqrt[n]{n!} = \infty$, so, letting $a \in \mathbb{R}$, be fixed, I'm trying to get $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^n < n!$ whenever $n>n_0$, but I can't figure it out.

I've been able to find a lower bound (possibly not too accurate), by AM-GM, but I can't conclude. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: $$
e^n  = 1 + n +  \ldots  + \frac{{n^n }}{{n!}} +  \ldots  > \frac{{n^n }}{{n!}} \Longrightarrow n! > \left( {\frac{n}{e}} \right)^n 
$$

Comment: Certainly $100^{100}<100!$, so there's an upper bound on $n$. Factorials are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A000142/b000142.txt and it should be pretty easy to answer the question by staring at that list.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Your inequality is the wrong way round. You have a strict lower bound on the minimum suitable $n$.

Comment: @Gary Thanks, I can find such $n_0$ with that. However, how can I find the lowest $n_0$?

Comment: @J.G., you're right, of course.

Comment: $\left\lceil {e\cdot a} \right\rceil$ will be very close to the optimal $n_0$.

Comment: Use the Stirling approximation to find the smallest solution.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/how-to-prove-an-n-for-all-n-sufficiently-large-and-n-leq-nn-for-al and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994010/prove-by-induction-that-7n-n-for-all-integer-n-ge-21

Comment: A better approximation is $n_0  = \left\lceil {\frac{1}{2}W\!\left( {\frac{{e^{2ae} }}{\pi }} \right)} \right\rceil$ which is probably optimal. Here $W$ is the Lambert-$W$ function.

Comment: Also https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-solve-n-100-n

Comment: @GerryMyerson The question in the body is more general than the one in the title. Depending on what the OP actually want, it may not be a duplicate.

Comment: @Gary, I can't read the mind of OP to know which question OP really wants, but I would hope that OP could work out the more general answer from the specific one.